# When class gets called part stack should get visible

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I am building an application as an Eclipse e4 RCP.

When a command handler class gets called then part stack should be made  visible dynamically.

So looking for a code I should use in class to make part stack visible.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail here. Is this an e4 RCP with an MPartStack declared in the Application.e4xmi or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP?

Comment: Also what does 'when a class get called' mean? Are you talking about a command handler?

Comment: e4 RCP I am talking about. I am talking about Handler class, when it gets called part stack should get visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the `MPartStack` to show initially turn off the `To Be Rendered` flag in the part stack design in the Applicatin.e4xmi:

[image: To Be Rendered flag]

In your command handler you can turn the 'to be rendered' flag on using something like:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(MApplication app, EModelService modelService)
{
  // Find the part stack element

  MUIElement partStack = modelService.find("part stack id", app);

  // Turn on rendering

  partStack.setToBeRendered(true);
}
```

Comment: What is not working? I tested this and it works fine for me, you need to be much more explicit about the problem. Is the handler running? Is it finding the part stack?

Comment: Sorry!! Due to different error it was not working. Its working fine now. Thank you!!